# Error checking on the MDriven models inside VS IDE

Tags: mdriven

I have a legacy system based on ECO III and now upgraded to MDriven. It works ok but there are quite a number of errors when I try to check for model error inside VS IDE:

[image]

The error messages look strange, I have no clue in what parts of  the model caused the error...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there may be "ghost" classes with name "" in your model.
Scroll the model tree - do you see rows with only the class symbol but no name?
Should it have a name or should it be deleted?

Comment: There is no ghost classes found by viewing inside the IDE. Anyway, after a few crashes and restarts of VS, the errors were gone now?! The model looks fine now...

Comment: Save followed by Load of model will strip away inconsistencies - so you had something strange but it is cleaned now